# Jquery setting class attribute not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have a CSS class and I wish to set it's width attribute:

```
ul.month-wrapper li
{
    font-size: 13px;
}
ul.year-wrapper li
{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

And the Jquery:

```
var MonthWidth = 30;
var YearWidth = MonthWidth * 12;

// Set CSS classes widths
$('ul.month-wrapper li').css('width', MonthWidth + 'px');
$('ul.year-wrapper li').css('width', YearWidth + 'px');
```

However this doesn't seem to do anything, widths remain unchanged!  Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to accept my previous answer by the way :P

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/rKePw/

Comment: Just a hint, but you really don't need the 'px' when setting css attributes with jQuery.

Comment: are you sure there are no other width marked as `!important` already being set?

Comment: @Felix King: it looks a lot wider than 30px

Comment: @naveen: `works` yes, but `It` is 30px (maybe I should have switched the assignment ;)). At least this is what the browser says. `works` is unchanged to have a comparison.

Comment: Are you sure you actually get to the css changing part? Maybe whatever event you are binding to doesn't fire correctly, maybe you don't have it inside document.ready? Try logging `console.log($('ul.month-wrapper li'))` to see if the elements you are trying to modify do already exist.

Comment: @naveen: Weird... works perfectly for me in Chrome: http://imgur.com/iA22x

Comment: @Felix it's way bigger than 30px for me in Chrome latest

Comment: my bad. i was looking at the second ul. hmmm.. taking a break.. sorry :) @Tom Gullen: its a teaser we are looking at the wrong li. the text 'work' may have spurred the wrong idea.

Comment: @Tom: The `It` list element is the one I changed. The `works` is for comparison... guess I really should switch it.

Comment: Doh!  Thanks!  It's solved anyway, I was setting the CSS setting before the LI's have been generated, seems a little counter intuitive but that's the cause anyway.  Thank you all for your time and help as always!

Comment: @Tom: The CSS is set directly on the elements. You cannot modify the elements before they exist :)

Comment: @Felix that makes sense,  I was thinking though I was modifying the CSS class though, so I modify the class *then* create dom elements that belong to that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add anything to a CSS class. The CSS class is static.

What you are doing above is adding the `width` style attribute to any controls on the page which are `li` within a `ul` with the class `.year-wrapper`

My guess is your running this script too soon in the page script, before the List Items have loaded into the page. Try the following to ensure the page has finished loading:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var MonthWidth = 30;
   var YearWidth = MonthWidth * 12;

   // Set CSS classes widths
   $('ul.month-wrapper li').css('width', MonthWidth + 'px');
   $('ul.year-wrapper li').css('width', YearWidth + 'px');

});
```

Comment: This is correct thank you, my code was before the li's were generated, not after.

Comment: CSS classes aren't static. You can modify them with javascript, just not with jQuery specifically.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to modify the classes you can use ordinary plain old Javascript, but there's nothing in jQuery to make it easier:

```
var ss = document.styleSheets[0];
if(ss.insertRule){
    ss.insertRule('ul.month-wrapper li {width: '+MonthWidth + 'px }', ss.cssRules.length);
    ss.insertRule('ul.year-wrapper li {width: '+YearWidth + 'px }', ss.cssRules.length);
}else if(ss.addRule){ // For IE only
    ss.addRule('ul.month-wrapper li', 'width: '+MonthWidth + 'px');
    ss.addRule('ul.year-wrapper li', 'width: '+YearWidth + 'px');
}
```

Example of cross browser adding rules to css class:

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/sMBeq/

That's just a simple example btw which appends new rules into the stylsheet. If you want to access the current rules and just add the `width:` style to them it get's slightly more complicated.